# How to branding / apply css on a dashboard e.g.: remove the header

Tags: dashboard

How could we brand/apply css on the green box part of a dashboard?

For example, I don't want the default icon or change the background color into blue or event remove this part.
How could we do that on a dashboard?

[image: inline]

Comment: I'm certainly no expert in the field of lightning UI customization but I'm pretty sure you would need to create your own lightning component "dashboard" that you could customize and style using the SLDS framework and CSS styling, but there are no native Dashboard components that you could pull into your custom component so you'd have to also create the dashboard components yourself and it would be pretty development heavy to build and maintain. For what purpose do you need to rebrand a dashboard inside Salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using out of the box components in Lightning Experience, you cannot customize anything out there as the attributes are not exposed for any extension. The section you are referring to on the Dashboard is an out of the box feature and something that you don't have access to, thus you cannot control any UX aspect in there.

However, if you want to customize the overall branding/look and feel of your Org, you can utilize [Lightning Themes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lightning_themes.htm). This can address some of your requirements, **but** remember that applying a Theme has an effect on your overall Org, instead of any specific component.

So unless you really customize your view, or you choose themes to impact your overall Org, you have limited choices here.